# Orchard 1.7 | NO Restore method in IContentManager

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

While migrating my Orchard 1.9.1 project to Orchard 1.7, We have used the Arana.VersionManager from Orchard gallery.

We further customized it to our needs and had used the `Restore` method of `Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManager` in 1.9.1

```
ContentItem Restore(ContentItem contentItem, VersionOptions options);
```

However, when we went back to Orchard 1.7, there is NO `Restore` method now. I really don't want to lose this `Restore` functionality. Please suggest next steps. Where is the CODE of this `Restore` method of Content Manager in 1.9.1 ? Can simply including the code in 1.7 will work ?

Comment: The code is in Orchard.Framework/ContentManagement/DefaultContentManager.cs:590

Comment: Why would you downgrade from 1.9 to 1.7?

Comment: His server didn't support 4.5.1